# How to refresh the jsp page when dispatcher is used from the servlet?

Tags: html, jsp, tomcat, servlets, refresh

I'm using Eclipse JUNO IDE and tomcat 7.0.

I have a web application. In the application I have:

1. Servlet
2. JSP pages
3. HTML - the main page.

In the main page I have a form which redirect to the servlet (because I need to get data from Server) when a submit-button is clicked and the servlet redirect to the match jsp page. 
Now when I'm refreshing the jsp page, the servlet get NULL in the request. so my question 
is how to resubmitting? because I want to display the new data from the server.

NOTE: The Servlet talks to the Server with sockets, so when user is pressing on some submit-button, the request redirect to the servlet and the servlet redirect the request
to the server to get the required data. Now when the servlet recieved the data, it's transporting the data to the jsp page, and the jsp page display it as html

```
    if (request.getParameter("submit").equals("Show Taxis at Driving"))
    {
           requests.add("driving");
           to_server.writeObject(requests);
           to_server.flush();
           requests.removeAllElements();

           try{
               driving = (Vector)from_server.readObject();
               request.setAttribute("driving", driving);
               //request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/driving_page.jsp").forward(request, response);
               RequestDispatcher disp = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/driving_page.jsp");
               disp.forward(request, response);
           }catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
    }
    else if (request.getParameter("submit").equals("Add Passenger to Taxi"))
    {
        requests.add("taxis");
        requests.add("passengers");
        to_server.writeObject(requests);
        to_server.flush();
        requests.removeAllElements();

        try {
            taxis_waiting  = (Vector)from_server.readObject();
            passengers = (Vector)from_server.readObject();
            request.setAttribute("taxis", taxis_waiting);
            request.setAttribute("passengers", passengers);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/add_passenger_to_taxi.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            request.getRequestDispatcher("error_page.jsp").forward(request, response);      
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a simplest and most common approach:

1. Your `index.html` page should have a form using `GET` action. This way form parameters are passed via query parameters to your servlet:

   ```
   /servlet?search=foo
   ```
2. Your servlet process the search and *forwards* to the `results.jsp` so that the browser still points to `/servlet?search=foo`:

   ```
   RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().
                                            getRequestDispatcher("results.jsp);
   dispatcher.forward(request,response);
   ```
3. If your user refreshes the page, she will hit `/servlet?search=foo` again, calling the server-side logic and refreshing the search results.

Comment: thanks for your response, but this is very same to what I did. In the 'MainPage.html' the form using the GET method and the action redirect to the servlet. now the servlet processing the request and forward it to the required jsp page. but when the user refreshing the jsp page, the servlet gets null.

Comment: @eliorsh: show your servlet code. If you are using request parameter and simple `request.getParameter(...)`, it should retrieve the parameter, no matter whether it was from a form or pasted manually in the URL.

Comment: I edited my question and added the servlet code, this code is 
from the 'doPost' method

Comment: @eliorsh: so are you using GET or POST to submit the form? You must use GET for this trick to work. Do you see `submit=...` parameter in your servlet URL in the browser? BTW relying on such verbose strings is not a good idea, consider some shorter codes. Change `doGet()` to `doPost()`, it should still work (and work as expected during refresh)

Comment: To submit the form I'm using the GET method. In the servlet
this code is within the 'doPost' method, but i'm calling the 'doPost'
method from the 'doGet' method. and about the strings I know, 
it just for me.. for debugging

Comment: BTW, the browser must know what is the request, even if the form is 
submmited by GET or POST method. no? so it should work..

Answer (score 1):

You can simply solve this problem using sessions. This will be a alternative solution.

```
if(session.getAttribute("REFRESH")!=null){
    response.sendRedirect("../your_servlet");
}
else{    
session.setAttribute("REFRESH","TRUE");
}
```

You can place the above code in the jsp page. 
When the page loads at first time it checks for the session value, but not such a session is saved so it creates a session as in the else part of the code. but after that when the user clicks the refresh button, then session has a value and redirection happens.

But to avoid circular redirection , you need to remove the session in the servelt. So bellow code should be placed in your servlet.

```
session.removeAttribute("REFRESH");
```